# How do I find who created a CloudFormation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

**How do I find who created a CloudFormation stack?**

I am using `boto3` to list the stacks whose status is `COMPLETE` along with the user who created the stack. I can get all the attributes of the stack but I am unable to find the user information in CloudFormation dashboard or in boto3 CF APIs. Any idea how to get the IAM username of the user that created the stack?

Thanks

Snippet of my code:

```
import boto3

cf  = boto3.client('cloudformation', region_name='us-east-1')
stacks = cf.list_stacks(StackStatusFilter=['CREATE_COMPLETE'])['StackSummaries']
names = [stack['StackName'] for stack in stacks]

for name in names:
  resources = cf.describe_stack_resources(StackName=name)['StackResources']
  ...
  ...
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get this information through CloudTrail.  In particular, call `lookup_events()` on the CloudTrail client:

```
events = cloudtrail_client.lookup_events(LookupAttributes=[{'AttributeKey':'EventName', 'AttributeValue':'CreateStack'}])
for event in events['Events']:
    event_detail = json.loads(event['CloudTrailEvent'])
    if event_detail['requestParameters']['stackName'] == myStackName:
        creator = event['Username']
```

Comment: I thought about using CloudTrail. But some of the stacks are more than 2 years old and our CloudTrail lifecycle policy is 6 months. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the IAM creator is exposed through the CloudFormation APIs anywhere.  Might be a good policy to pass it in as a template parameter, but that won't help with existing stacks.  Sorry.

Comment: But if I launch an instance in CloudFormation, the instance's RunInstances() has an attribute for IAM user. Internally AWS must fetch the username based on the passed credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Use Cloud Trail service api call `lookup_events()` with AttributeKey 'EventName', AttributeValue:'CreateStack'

Comment: Add some explanation to the answer. Only telling about the API will not help.