# Through aws cli - how can i get the arn of the entity that created an eks cluster?

Tags: amazon-eks

According to this -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html

The user who created the cluster gets an admin role automatically.

How do i know through cli who created a specific eks cluster?

Comment: If you want to know a user/role used to create this cluster then use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/describe-cluster.html and check arn.

Comment: Thats the arn of the cluster, not the user who created it (i need it to identify kubernetes-admin user without searching the audits)

Comment: According to aws case ive opened - its currently not possible after 90 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to whoever searches it - i've opened a case with amazon, it's not possible if the events of cloudtrail are cleared.

also seems not possible to find it from the stack details:
[How do I find who created a CloudFormation stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36485632/how-do-i-find-who-created-a-cloudformation-stack)

What i've done - is to also search it in the kubernetes logs (if audits are enabled and the admin performed an action in the last X days).